# Tizen Web App Custom Sound

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-emulator

In the tizen web app for wearable (Tizen 3.0) i want to play a custom sound for a notification, the html source code is :

```
 <div class="ui-content content-padding-timer" >
    <audio id="myaudio" src="sound/ding.mp3"></audio>
    <div id="wk-timer">0</div>
    <div id="cc-timer">cycles: 0</div>
</div>
```

and the js part to trigger it :

```
 var ding = document.querySelector('#myaudio');
 ding.pause();
 ding.load();
 ding.play();
```

***This works perfectly in the emulator*** but when i try it on a actual device (Gear S3) the app crashes and exists with no real error.

I really appreciate any tips since i've been struggling with this for some time.

**Update:**

I've submitted a bug report [here](https://bugs.tizen.org/browse/TW-66)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Checking your query I've deployed your code on:

1) Gear S3 running on Tizen 2.3.2

2) Gear Sport running on Tizen 3.0

The audio resource plays well on Tizen 2.3.2 device, But when It comes to Tizen 3.0 the audio resource isn't played. I've cross-checked on multiple devices.

Seems a Tizen bug....You may report a bug on [Tizen bug Tracker](https://bugs.tizen.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa). Here’s a guideline on [how to report bugs](https://www.tizen.org/community/bug-tracker/how-report-bugs?langswitch=en&langredirect=1). Please share the 'Reported bug' link here on this post to help the developers keep track.

Comment: cool, ty for the help :D i'll report this and come back with an answer